# BinarySearchTree in c - deleteWord - keep reference to element deleted from tree

Tags: c, malloc, root, binary-search-tree

I'm asked to do a project for school which is a dictionary using a binary search tree. 
I have a big issue using my removeWord function. 
I need to free the word I need to delete but I can't keep a pointer to it when I'm deleting the root. 
Here is my code (I just kept one case cause I doubt you'd need more, so it would be easier to read. But if you do just tell me)

```
void removeWord(BST* tree, char* word)
{
    BST* matchWord = getWord(tree, word); //point to the node matching the word to delete
    if (matchWord->rightSon == NULL)
    {
        *tree = *(transplant(tree, matchWord, matchWord->leftSon));
    }
    free(matchWord); //matchWord point to the new root of the tree so iznogoud
}

BST* transplant(BST* tree, BST* first, BST* second)
{
    if (first->parent == NULL)
    {
        tree = second; //here wordMatch becomes second as well and I don't want to
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: you have to change the address of tree instead of changing the value pointed. If you change the value, you do not need to free that memory.

Comment: so basically instead of 
*tree = *transplant
I should write
tree = transplant ?
but in that case tree outside my removeWord function will point to the old root

Comment: Did not catch why if parent != NULL it should be tree. matchword can be in any lower level and we need to reset its parent pointer. 
Also, "matchword point to the new root.." - what's the matter on what it points if you are deleting it.

Comment: if parent == NULL that means I want to delete the root.
So the new root would be the second element.

But when I do it this way, matchWord also points to the new root instead of the old one. 
If I don't free the old root (which is not in the tree anymore so it's useless) there would be memory leak

Answer (score 0):

Find below solution which may help you to complete your project:

```
void removeWord(BST* tree, char* word)
{
   //point to the node matching the word to delete
   BST* matchWord = getWord(tree, word);
   //If word matches then it's not NULL
   if (NULL != matchWord)
   {
      //Find right son if NULL then 
      //we need to transplant left son to parent position
      Transplant(tree, matchWord);

      //Remove memory of removed node
      free(matchWord);
      matchWord = NULL;
   }
}

int transplant(BST* tree, BST* matchWord)
{
   if (NULL != matchWord->leftSon)
   {
      //Here you need to apply logic which saves matchWord's leftSon to parent's son location where matchWord is present.
      //And also have to check if matchWord is having rightSon then rightSon branch is also need to be saved at right position of matchWord.
   }
   else if (NULL != matchWord->rightSon)
   {
      //Here you need to apply logic which saves matchWord's rightSon to parent's son location where matchWord is present.
      //And also have to check if matchWord is having leftSon then leftSon branch is also need to be saved at left position of matchWord.
   }
   else
   {
      //Here you need to remove matchWord's location from it's parent branches.
   }
}
```

If any doubts then please let me know.
You may need to understand BST first thoroughly before doing the program on it which helps you a lot.
You can find details from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: I don't need to know how to remove a node from a tree. I've already done that. The problem is I don't know how to access the original matchWord after I put it out of the tree. Here is my code.

http://pastebin.com/iiGswVY9

Comment: If you want to remove that word then after why you need that original matched word.

Comment: Because this element would still be in the memory if I don't use free() on it

Comment: So you are saying as per your program implementation matchWord's address got changed and if so then take one more pointer and before doing any process copy matchWord's pointer address in other reference pointer and at last you can free it using that reference pointer.

Comment: The only way I found to get a pointer to finally point to the original matchWord was to use
BST* test = malloc(sizeof(BST));
*test = *matchWord
or something like that.
But that means I would have to free that new memory i just allocated but I wouldn't have any pointer to it anymore. So it just end up the same. But maybe I'm missing something ... I'm kinda new to the concept of pointers.

Comment: No it's not require to allocate memory to that reference pointer, as you only assigning address of matchWord pointer to reference pointer you don't need to free any other memory. If you want to check memory addresses of both pointer then you can use printf("matchWord: %p, test: %p\n", matchWord, test); that both are same so by freeing any one of them you are able to free that memory.